# Creating boxes with borders in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, screen-resolution

So my problem is that I'm trying to create some boxes (div with border on it) on a page and then put things inside of them later. However, I need these boxes to stay the same size on different screen resolutions. 
So of course I can create the box by explicitly giving the div a width, and height property. However, even if I use em for sizing, it changes on different screen resolutions. And it is finicky. 
I can also set the height and div using jQuery by finding the height/width of the document/window and doing the size from there. Here it basically stays the right size, but it is very finicky.

So since bootstrap-3 already solved a lot of these problems, is there anyway I can use bootstraps `class='col-md-` to create these boxes?

Last ditch I guess I could set the width and height of them for all the different screen resolutions. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: "I need these boxes to stay the same size on different screen resolutions" - same proportions (fluid) or same pixel size?

Comment: same proportions. I've basically decided to just use jQuery sizing since it proved to be less finicky than I originally thought.